iOS Universal Links not Opening App, Opening in Browser Instead
I'm facing an issue with implementing Universal Links (applinks) in my iOS app. I've followed the necessary steps outlined in the Apple documentation [link to documentation], but the links still open in the browser instead of opening the app.
Here's what I've done so far:

Hosted the apple-app-site-association file at
www.domain.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association with the
following content:

     {
      "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
          {
            "appID": "[teamID].[BundleID]",
            "paths": ["*", "/" ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }


Added Associated Domains capability in Xcode and added the domains
applinks:domain.com and applinks:www.domain.com.

Despite following these steps, the app links still open in the browser instead of opening the app directly.
I'm not sure what could be causing this issue. Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated.


Please check this articles for the steps, https://medium.com/wolox/ios-deep-linking-url-scheme-vs-universal-links-50abd3802f97, in this artcle, check your universal link https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/

@Shivbaba'sson, After checking the AASA file, I discovered the root cause of the issue. I received a 401 status, indicating that Apple couldn't access the AASA file. Thank you for your assistance ✌️
